# return 2nd previous workday

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to query the second previous work day from the current date from this date table. So If i run this today i need to return  '2021-05-07'. The Work Day field is populated with 0 when the date is a weekend date or holiday, so i need this filtered for rows with 1.

i'm pulling from a calendar table that is populated from an excel file. this is a custom fiscal calendar. the only other fields are fiscal period, year, etc, here's a sample:

```
Date        Work Day
2021-05-11     1
2021-05-10     1
2021-05-09     0
2021-05-08     0
2021-05-07     1
```

this query works to return the previous day

```
                              select wrk.[date]
                              from

                             (SELECT 
                             cast([Date] as date) as 'Date',
                             cast([Work Day] as int) as 'Work Day'
                             FROM calendar           
                             where [Work Day] = '1') as wrk

                             where wrk.[date] = cast(dateadd(day,-1,getdate()) as date)
```

but when i adjust to go back two days it returns null

```
                              select wrk.[date]
                              from

                             (SELECT 
                             cast([Date] as date) as 'Date',
                             cast([Work Day] as int) as 'Work Day'
                             FROM calendar           
                             where [Work Day] = '1') as wrk

                             where wrk.[date] = cast(dateadd(day,-2,getdate()) as date)
```

Comment: Please define "work day".  Do you have a calendar table with this information?  What about holidays?

Comment: A calendar table is your friend. This would be very easy with one.

Comment: Calendar tables are key to this kind of stuff, don't leave home without one.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Work Day is populated with 0 when the date is a weekend or holiday date, so i need this filtered for rows with a 1. this is a custom fiscal calendar created in excel, but i'm using it as a table in my DW DB. the only other fields in the table are fiscal period, year, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 select TOP (1) wrk.[Date]
  from
  
     (SELECT 
     cast([Date] as date) as 'Date',
     cast([Work Day] as int) as 'Work Day'
     FROM calendar           
     where [Work Day] = '1'
     ) as wrk
 where wrk.[date] <= (select(cast(dateadd(day,-2,getdate()) as date)))
 ORDER BY  wrk.[date] desc
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your second query returns nothing because you ask

```
where wrk.[date] = cast(dateadd(day,-2,getdate()) as date)
```

Which basically means, 2 days from today, ie 2021-05-09.

But your nested query removed that day because you filtered on the open days only. Thus there's no result.

What you should do is asking the nearest date from  "today - 2"

```
  select TOP (1) wrk.[date]
  from
  
     (SELECT 
     cast([Date] as date) as 'Date',
     cast([Work Day] as int) as 'Work Day'
     FROM calendar           
     where [Work Day] = '1'
     ) as wrk
 where wrk.[date] <= cast(dateadd(day,-2,getdate()) as date
 ORDER BY  wrk.[date]
```